# Maintain this in a method passed by reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the following example, to send as parameter to the method "lostThis" object "instObj", "this" is the window object.

```
var obj = function() {};
obj.prototype.lostThis = function() {
    console.log('lostThis', this instanceof obj, this);
};

var instObj = new obj;

var caller = {
    runFn: function(fn) {
        fn();
    }
};

caller.runFn(instObj.lostThis);
```

Console response:

```
lostThis false Window
```

[run example](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/tkQYV/)

In the following example (slightly more complex) there are different ways to call the methods of "instObj" where it is the same and others where I can keep the "this" object.

```
var obj = function() {};

obj.prototype.methodRefHasThis = function() {
    var t = this;
    return function() {
        console.log('methodRefHasThis ', t instanceof obj, t);
    };
};

obj.prototype.methodRefLostThis = function() {
    console.log('methodRefLostThis ', this instanceof obj, this);
};

obj.prototype.methodRefMaybeThis = function() {
    console.log('methodRefMaybeThis ', this instanceof obj, this);
};

var instObj = new obj;
var caller = {
    runFn: function(fn) {
        fn();
    }
};

// width jQuery
$('button')
    .bind('click', instObj.methodRefHasThis())
    .bind('click', instObj.methodRefLostThis);

caller.runFn(instObj.methodRefHasThis());
caller.runFn(instObj.methodRefLostThis);
caller.runFn(function() {
    instObj.methodRefMaybeThis();
});​
```

Console response:

```
methodRefHasThis  true obj
methodRefLostThis  false Window
methodRefMaybeThis  true obj

methodRefHasThis  true obj
methodRefLostThis  false <button>​press here​</button>​
```

[run example](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/N95Y3/2/)

I understand that this happens with jQuery to assign the method to an event, but **could I call the method "methodRefLostThis" no lose "this" object to be passed by reference?**

thanks

**Solution by @am_not_i_am , @Dan_Davies_Brackett and @Ben_Lee**

```
var obj = function() {};
obj.prototype.lostThis = function() {
    console.log('lostThis', this instanceof obj, this);
};

var instObj = new obj;

var caller = {
    runFn: function(fn) {
        fn();
    }
};

caller.runFn(instObj.lostThis.bind(instObj));
caller.runFn($.proxy(instObj.lostThis, instObj));
```

Console response:

```
lostThis true obj
lostThis true obj

 ​
```

[run example](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/7VUGm/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use one of the techniques that you've found to work, you can use `Function.prototype.bind` to bind the calling context to a new function...

```
caller.runFn(instObj.lostThis.bind(instObj));
```

This returns a new function that when invoked, will set the calling context to whatever you passed as the first argument to `.bind()`.

Any additional arguments passed to `.bind()` will be set as fixed arguments to the returned function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bind` to bind an object to `this` in the callee. For example:

```
caller.runFn(instObj.lostThis.bind(this));
```

Here, the `this` at the point the method is run will be transferred to the `this` in `lostThis`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to solve this problem.  Either you can capture a local reference to `this` (I usually call it `self`) and then use `self.` instead of `this.` inside the method, or you can use function binding.

Ben Lee gave the JS5 way to do binding; [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)  is an alternative for browsers that don't support `Function.bind`.